# Server can't read object from client socket stream, why?

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I have a server that wait in a loop for clients to connect. Once a client connect a new thread is created to handle that client requests. The server and the client connect with each other easily, but the problem I have with that thread is that it doesn't seem to read the object that the client send to the pipe. I've checked everywhere but can't seem to find the problem.

The server code:

```
public class Server 
{
    private ServerSocket server;

    public Server(int port) throws IOException
    {
        //Port 9367
        this.server = new ServerSocket(port);
        this.server.setReuseAddress(true);
    }

    public void start() throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Waiting for client...");
        while(true)
        {
            new Thread(new ClientRequestManager(server.accept())).start();
            System.out.println("client found !");
        }
    }
}
```

ClientRequestManager code:

```
public void run() 
{
    try {
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

        System.out.println("Waiting for request...");
        while(true)
        {
            DataRequest request = (DataRequest)objectInput.readObject();

            if(request instanceof TestDataRequest)
            {
                new Thread(new TestEntityManager((TestDataRequest)request, this.clientSocket)).start();
                System.out.println("Client dispatched to the test entity manager !");
            }
            System.out.println("Can't find the right entity manager !");          
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { }   
}
```

The server seem to get stuck here: DataRequest request = (DataRequest)objectInput.readObject();

Here's the basic code I've written for the client to test the server:

```
        //TestDataRequest inherit DataRequest
    TestDataRequest request = new TestDataRequest();
    request.setID(30);
    request.setDescription("test");

    Socket serverSocket = new Socket("localhost",9367);

    ObjectOutputStream clientOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(serverSocket.getOutputStream());

    System.out.println("Sending data...");
    clientOutputStream.writeObject(request);
    clientOutputStream.flush();
    System.out.println("Data send !");
```

I don't get any error, the thread just block. I suppose it's waiting for object to be written to the pipe, like it should be, but it's still blocking when a client write an object to the pipe. I don't understand why. The object implements serializable... The server and the client seem to be connected to each other and writing/reading to the same pipe...

The server: addr=/127.0.0.1,port=49654,localport=9367

The client: addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=9367,localport=49654

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you put some more System.out.println calls to make sure it's blocking in the readObject call?

Comment: `catch (Exception e) { }` ... stopped reading at that point.

Comment: LOL. Okay, I didn't see that. I get an invalidClass exception. That was stupid of me. I got caught up in the whole socket thing, I didn't even think of the kind of exceptions I was catching. Thanks anyway :P

Comment: In Server should get clientSocket instance before creating new Thread since accept blocks:

 `Socket clientSocket = server.accept();
 new Thread(new ClientRequestManager(clientSocket)).start();`

Likewise should readObject as Object (no casting) then use instanceof to check if it expected class:

 `Object (request = objectInput.readObject();
 if(request instanceof TestDataRequest)...`